# Identify two ICs from Laptop Motherboard

Tags: identification

Can anyone identify these two ICs from a laptop motherboard?

[image]

[image]

Comment: forgot to mention that this is a laptop motherboard.

Comment: Considering everything points to these being power supply ICs: if they have failed, they've with a high likelihood fried something else, too. That's not absolutely certain, but if you're assuming that "just" replacing these ICs will fix your notebook: expect to research much deeper.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a step down controler.
You can find here the datasheet : [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps51285a.pdf).

For replacements, I invite you go on the TI power supply test bench and simulate the need of your circuit. The website will advise you the proper chip. [Link here](http://www.ti.com/design-tools/webench-power-design/power-designer.html)